# Safari on my 2007 iMac running snow leopard gives me an error that it can’t establish a secure connection to the server (XXXX.com)

Tags: safari, wifi, imac, security, snow-leopard

I have a 2007 iMac and was recently formatted to give to a friend. It was working perfectly before this and always updated as far as it could go.  When formatted I installed snow leopard.  When opening Safari I realized it would not open ANY website.  It brought me to the site but wouldn’t open giving me the above error message.  I have deleted cache, reset, rebooted, re-installed.  I have deleted history and there were no extensions.  The older version doesn’t have a “Privacy” tab but has security.  I have done just about everything suggested but to no avail.  I am usually pretty good at figuring out but this has stumped me.  Any suggestions.  I have updated and can go no further.  I bought a copy of ElCapitan (coming in the mail) in the hopes it will solve my problems but I do need help.  My server is strong and dependable…wifi and ethernet are connected

Comment: Your browser is woefully out of date and no longer supports the security required by modern web servers.   You either have to get a browser that runs on SL or a newer OS.  El Cap might work, but it too is obsolete and no longer getting security updated.